# JDBi3 UnableToCreateStatementException: No argument factory registered for 'false' of qualified type org.jdbi.v3.core.argument.NullArgument

Tags: java, null, boolean, jdbi, jdbi3

I'm running into a strange issue where if I try to bind("paramName", false) to a nullable boolean (SQL bit) in my database, I receive the following error:

```
org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.UnableToCreateStatementException: No argument factory registered for 'false' of qualified type org.jdbi.v3.core.argument.NullArgument [statement:"UPDATE dbo.TagValues SET BoolValue = :boolValue, NumericValue = :numericValue, StringValue = :stringValue WHERE TagID = :tagID", arguments:{positional:{}, named:{stringValue:NULL,tagID:17,numericValue:NULL,boolValue:false}, finder:[]}]
```

I am using MSSQL Server 2017 and JDBi 3. All 3 of my colon delineated parameters boolValue, numericValue, and stringValue are all nullable.

The weird thing is, I am hardcoding the boolean value, and that is the only instance where the statement seems to barf. I've attached the code, with the offending line. Sorry ahead of time for the line lengths.

```
        PreparedBatch batch = handle.prepareBatch("UPDATE dbo.TagValues SET BoolValue = :boolValue, NumericValue = :numericValue, StringValue = :stringValue WHERE TagID = :tagID");

        active_sites.forEach(site -> site.getEntryPoints().forEach(entryPoint -> {
            if(entryPoint.isGatewayResponding() && !entryPoint.hasError()){
                entryPoint.getTiedTags().forEach(tag -> {
                    if (boolTypes.contains(tag.getType())) {
                        batch.bind("boolValue", tag.getValue().getValue()).bindNull("numericValue", Types.FLOAT).bindNull("stringValue", Types.VARCHAR).bind("tagID", tag.getIDX()).add();
                    }
                    else if (numericTypes.contains(tag.getType())) {
                        batch.bindNull("boolValue", Types.BIT).bind("numericValue", tag.getValue().getValue()).bindNull("stringValue", Types.VARCHAR).bind("tagID", tag.getIDX()).add();
                    }
                    else if (stringTypes.contains(tag.getType())) {
                        batch.bindNull("boolValue", Types.BIT).bindNull("numericValue", Types.FLOAT).bind("stringValue", tag.getValue().getValue()).bind("tagID", tag.getIDX()).add();
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                entryPoint.getTiedTags().forEach(tag -> batch.bindNull("boolValue", Types.BIT).bindNull("numericValue", Types.FLOAT).bindNull("stringValue", Types.VARCHAR).bind("tagID", tag.getIDX()).add());
            }

            entryPoint.getErrorTags().stream().filter(tag -> tag.getType() == 33 || tag.getType() == 34 || tag.getType() == 35).forEach(tag -> {
                if(Objects.nonNull(tag.getValue())) {
                    batch.bind("boolValue", tag.getValue().getValue()).bindNull("numericValue", Types.FLOAT).bindNull("stringValue", Types.VARCHAR).bind("tagID", tag.getIDX()).add();
                }
                else {
                        //TAG 17 FALLS INTO THIS CATEGORY, CONFIRMED BY PRINTLN. THIS IS THE OFFENDER.
                        batch.bind("boolValue", false).bindNull("numericValue", Types.FLOAT).bindNull("stringValue", Types.VARCHAR).bind("tagID", tag.getIDX()).add();
                    }
                });
            }));
```

Update:

jdbi: 3.18.1
mssql jdbc driver: 9.2.1.jre15

Full stacktrace:

```
org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.UnableToCreateStatementException: No argument factory registered for 'false' of qualified type org.jdbi.v3.core.argument.NullArgument [statement:"UPDATE dbo.TagValues SET BoolValue = :boolValue, NumericValue = :numericValue, StringValue = :stringValue WHERE TagID = :tagID", arguments:{positional:{}, named:{stringValue:NULL,tagID:17,numericValue:NULL,boolValue:false}, finder:[]}]
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.ArgumentBinder.factoryNotFound(ArgumentBinder.java:174)
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.ArgumentBinder.lambda$null$2(ArgumentBinder.java:141)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:403)
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.ArgumentBinder.lambda$null$3(ArgumentBinder.java:141)
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.ArgumentBinder.lambda$null$4(ArgumentBinder.java:142)
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.ArgumentBinder$Prepared.lambda$prepareBinder$12(ArgumentBinder.java:230)
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.ArgumentBinder.lambda$wrapExceptions$6(ArgumentBinder.java:153)
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.ArgumentBinder$Prepared.lambda$null$13(ArgumentBinder.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.ArgumentBinder$Prepared.lambda$prepareBinder$14(ArgumentBinder.java:234)
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.ArgumentBinder$Prepared.bindNamed(ArgumentBinder.java:240)
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.ArgumentBinder.bind(ArgumentBinder.java:60)
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.PreparedBatch.internalBatchExecute(PreparedBatch.java:204)
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.PreparedBatch.execute(PreparedBatch.java:108)
    at app.dao.services.impl.EntryDaoService.updateTagValues(EntryDaoService.java:165)
    at app.SCADA.updateTagValues(SCADA.java:215)
    at app.SCADA.run(SCADA.java:93)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

Update: This was in fact a bug with JDBi where it couldn't bind null to a column for a row or rows when other rows in the same batch have the same parameters and contain data. This was resolved I believe in JDBi 3.24+

Comment: Please, provide full stacktrace and exact version of JDBI and JDBC driver you are using.

Comment: @YuriiMelnychuk updated with the information you requested.

Comment: Played a little bit with it and looks like it is a bug, filed an issue: https://github.com/jdbi/jdbi/issues/1901